# Que remplace le pronom « y » dans l'expression « il y a » ?

Tags: expressions, pronoms, indications-de-lieu

Je sais que normalement on utilise le pronom « y » pour remplacer les noms précédés par la préposition « à ». Mais je ne comprends pas pourquoi on l'utilise aussi dans cette expression. Peut-on le remplacer avec *« à + qqch »* dans ce cas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans *il y a*, le *y* ne remplace plus rien.

Pour Grevisse, *le bon usage*, 12<sup>ième</sup> édition, on peut considérer que *y avoir* et *s'agir* sont des verbes essentiellement impersonnels distincts d'*avoir* et d'*agir*.  Le *y* dans *il y a* n'a donc pas plus de fonction grammaticale et ne représente rien de plus que le pronom des verbes essentiellement pronominaux, c'est-à-dire pas grand chose.

De plus, il classe *il y a* dans les introducteurs, et les introducteurs font aussi partie des structures figées dont l'analyse des composants n'a guère qu'une valeur historique.

Answer (score 4):

"*Y*" désigne un lieu précis et remplace donc "*ici*" ou "*là*". Des phrases comme "*il y a un couteau ici*" comportent donc une redite.

Fais cependant attention car dans certaines régions les gens y ont tendance à abuser du "*y*" et l'y mettent à toutes les sauces dans toutes les phrases.

---

"*Y*" refers to a precise place and is consequently a synonym of *there* or *here*. So French sentences like "*il y a un couteau ici*" (there is a knife here) get an obvious repetition.

However be careful because in some regions people tend to abuse of "*y*" in their sentences and use it absolutely everywhere, especially when it has nothing to do here.

Comment: Oh, ben si ça y gêne qu'on en abuse, on va y voir ce qu'on peut faire.

Comment: Hm... il y a des Lyonnais dans le coin.

Answer (score 3):

Dans ce contexte, et d'[après le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y) :

- *Y* forme des locutions dans lesquelles il peut s'interpréter comme l'équivalent, à l'origine de *là* ou de *à cela*

  > *Il y a un chien dans la cour.*

  est l'équivalent de

  > *Là, dans la cour, se trouve un chien.*

  Quant à *à cela* :

  > *Je ne veux pas procéder de cette façon. J'y vois un inconvénient.*

  est l'équivalent de

  > *Je ne veux pas procéder de cette façon. Je vois un inconvénient à cela.*

Selon ce même TLF, et plus particulièrement aux lieux :

- *Y*, pronom adverbial, représente le lieu où l'on est ou le lieu où l'on va. Il s'oppose ainsi à en qui représente le lieu d'origine

  > *J'irai au cinéma pour y voir un film.*

  a la même signification que la phrase suivante :

  > *J'irai au cinéma pour voir un film en ce lieu.*

  Mais cette dernière phrase est lourde, et ne correspond pas à l'usage courant. C'est pourquoi on utilise *y*.

Il existe un troisième sens à *y*, mais il me semble s'éloigner de ta question.
En tous les cas, on ne peut pas remplacer *y* par *à + qqch*.