# La provenance/L'intuition de « y » dans les expressions idiomatiques

Tags: pronoms, expressions-idiomatiques

Je veux trouver l'intuition du pronom « y » et connaître sa provenance dans les expressions idiomatiques suivantes, en dépit du fait que la p. 147 du *Advanced French Grammar* (de Véronique Mazet) affirme ce qui suit. J'ai déjà consulté [Que remplace le pronom « y » dans l'expression « il y a » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6664/que-remplace-le-pronom-y-dans-lexpression-il-y-a).

> In the following idiomatic expressions, do not try to find an English equivalent for **y**.
>
> I. Il s'**y** prend bien/mal. = He is going about it well/wrong.
> II. Ça **y** est ! = That's done!/Finished!
> III. Je n'**y** suis pour rien = I have nothing to do with it.
> IV. Je n'**y** peux pour rien = I can't do anything about it.
> V. Il **y** va de X. = X is on the line/at stake.

La phrase I me semble sensée, car il semble logique d'écrire « Il se prend bien/mal **à quelque chose** ». Mais quid des autres ?

**Question 1.** Ça **y** est. = *Ça est **à quelque chose**.*
La phrase en italique apparaît n'avoir aucun sens.

**Question 2.** Je n'**y** peux/suis pour rien. = *Je ne peux/suis pour rien **à quelque chose**.*
La phrase en italique apparaît n'avoir aucun sens.

**Question 3.** Pourquoi y a-t-il un « ne » dans la phrase III, qui ne semble pas être un ne explétif?

**Question 4.** Il **y** va de X. = *Il va de X **à quelque chose**.*
La phrase en italique apparaît n'avoir aucun sens.

Comment: Note : attention, comme pour toutes les autres expressions idiomatiques citées ici, « **il se prend mal à quelque chose* » n'est pas possible sans pronom, un francophone ne comprendrait probablement pas.

Answer (score 2):

Un peu comme pour les verbes pronominaux et pour [*y avoir*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6664/176), [*s'y prendre*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/prendre) et [*y aller de qqch*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/aller) me semblent être difficilement analysables et peuvent être considérés comme indépendants.

J'ai une hypothèse sur l'origine de *ça y est*, j'ai personnellement une image mentale de quelqu'un faisant rentrer une pièce (qui serait désignée par *ça*) dans un emplacement bien ajusté (le *y*).

[*Être pour qqch dans qqch*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%AAtre) est connu (sens 7a). Si une classe d'antécédents de *y* est constituée par les compléments d'objets indirects introduits par *à*, ce pronom aussi avoir pour antécédent des compléments adverbiaux introduits par d'autres prépositions que *à*, en particulier — mais pas exclusivement — quand ils désignent des lieux ou assimilés.

Comment: Merci de vos opinions. Les avez-vous vers la questions #3 et #4?

Comment: #4 est traité dans le premier paragraphe, _ne ... rien_ me semblait être une négation très classique ne méritant pas de commentaires mais _a posteriori_ la présence d'une préposition avant _rien_ est peut-être perturbante.

Answer (score 1):

Y :

- en tant que pronom personnel remplace 'à cela, à quelque chose, à quelqu'un...'

  Tu te rappelles de Corinne ? Je n'y pense plus. (je ne pense plus à elle)

  Je n'y manquerai pas (le ne est la négation)

  il ne faut pas chercher systématiquement à remplacer Y (ou EN) par ce qu'il est sensé représenter. Dans la tournure de phrase employée avec 'Y/EN', les mots qu'ils remplacent ne conviennent pas toujours
- en tant qu'adverbe il représente l'endroit où l'on est, ou la situation dans laquelle on se trouve

  J'y suis, j'y reste

  Il y a
- ensuite il y a beaucoup de locutions dont '**il y va de**...' (signifiant que quelque chose est mis en cause). Néanmoins on sent que **'y'** fait référence à la situation.

Comment: En effet, dans toutes les expressions idiomatiques qui ont été proposées dans la question « *y* fait référence à la situation ». C'est une bonne remarque, et c'est celle qui répond à la question.

Comment: @mlwacosmos: Merci encore une fois. Puisque j'ai déjà compris l'utilité générale du pronom « y », pourriez-vous SVP à vous intéresser à chaque question individuellement ? Je prends la question #4 par exemple : Il **y** va de X = Il va de X **à la situation** ??? Ceci semble n'avoir aucun sens !

Comment: @LePressentiment  Il y va de X = Il va *à partir* de X, ou, il y va de X [pour aller] vers Y

Comment: @LePressentiment Il y va de sa réputation : sa réputation est engagée si la situation actuelle prouve une malversation, un faux témoignage, ou autres crimes ou délits. Il n'y a pas de notion d'espace, mais de conséquence conditionnelle