# Différence entre « ne voyait plus » et « n'y voyait plus » : à quoi sert le pronom ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, pronoms, verbes-pronominaux

Page 52 dans *Advanced French Grammar*,  V. Mazet écrit ceci :

> Il n'**y** voyait plus parce que ses lunettes étaient cassées.
>    = He could not see anymore because his glasses were broken.

Pourquoi y a-t-il un ***y*** ici ? Quel est son antécédent ?

D'après moi :

> Il n'**y** voyait plus parce que ses lunettes étaient cassées.
>   = He could not see {*préposition comme à/dans/sur/…*} + {*un nom*} because his glasses were broken.

J'ai consulté [La provenance/L'intuition de « y » dans les expressions idiomatiques](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6703/la-provenance-lintuition-de-y-dans-les-expressions-idiomatiques?lq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans ce cas, il n'y a pas d'antécédent clair à *y* et on peut sans aucun changement de sens remplacer *n'y voyait* par *ne voyait*. On est donc dans le cas du dernier point de [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6709/82) :

> Néanmoins, on sent que *y* fait référence à la situation.

Answer (score 2):

Je pense qu'il s'agit du « y » qui, par sa fonction, désigne plutôt ici un lieu ou un moment précis.

Les deux sont corrects mais on dira plus facilement, par exemple, qu'il fait tout noir et que donc par conséquent on n'y voit plus rien.

Alors que dans le cas d'un aveugle par exemple, on privilégiera « il ne voit rien » plutôt que l'autre version.

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant.