# La provenance/L'intuition de « en » dans les expressions idiomatiques

Tags: pronoms, expressions-idiomatiques

Je veux trouver l'intuition du pronom « en » et connaître sa provenance dans les expressions idiomatiques suivantes, en dépit du fait que la p. 151 du *Advanced French Grammar* (de Véronique Mazet) affirme ceci :

> Do not try to find an English equivalent for **en** in the following expressions.
>   I. Je n'**en** peux plus! = I can't take it anymore.
>   II. Ç'**en** est fait de X. = That's the end of X.

**Question 1**. Je n'**en** peux plus! = *Je ne peux plus **de quelque chose.***
La phrase en italique apparaît n'avoir aucun sens.

**Question 2.** Devrait-il y avoir un autre verbe dans la phrase I? Si la phrase comprenait *SUPPORTER* et devenait « *Je ne peux plus SUPPORTER **de quelque chose*** », je serais moins désorienté.

Néanmoins, je sais que *supporter* est un verbe transitif. Si j'avais dit « *Je ne peux plus supporter **quelque chose*** », cette phrase n'aurait pas compris le pronom « de ». Par conséquent, le pronom « en » n'apparaîtra pas dans l'idiotisme et cet idiotisme cesse d'exister.

**Question 3.** Ç'**en** est fait de X. = *Ça/Cela est fait de X **de quelque chose***.
La phrase en italique apparaît n'avoir aucun sens.

Comment: Il me semble que la situation est similaire à celle ici : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6664/que-remplace-le-pronom-y-dans-lexpression-il-y-a

Answer (score 3):

EN :

- en tant qu'adverbe il indique la provenance, l'origine (l'intuition ?? je ne vois pas) :

  Tu es allé chez tes parents? - j'en viens
- en tant que pronom personnel, il remplace 'de cela, de lui, d'elle, d'eux ...)

  Je n'en peux plus, je n'en sais rien, j'en suis sûr
- sinon c'est une préposition à mettre devant certains mots pour indiquer le lieu (en France), la matière (en verre), le moyen (en voiture, en bateau), la durée (en 5 minutes), devant un participe présent (en arrivant, en chantant) et d'autres expressions à connaitre

Comment: Il me semble que l'intuition de « la situation » que tu fournis [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6703/la-provenance-lintuition-de-y-dans-les-expressions-idiomatiques) est une fois de plus pertinente. À la place d'ajouter quelque chose à la situation, dans ces phrases quelque chose résulte de la situation.

Comment: @mlwacosmos: Merci de votre réponse. Puisque j'ai déjà compris l'utilité générale du pronom « en », je cherche des réponses à chacune de mes questions ci-dessus.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Merci beaucoup encore, mais je reste désorienté. Même si je remplace **de quelque chose** par **de la situation**, j'obtiendrai toujours les non-sens. SVP, pourriez-vous aborder les 3 questions un par un?

Comment: Comme je l'ai dit pour le 'y' : il est inutile de remplacer en ou y par ce qu'il est sensé représenter. La tournure de phrase correspond à l'utilisation de 'en' ou 'y'. Réponse à vos 3 questions : on ne remplace pas ou on change la tournure de phrase pour remplacer en par 'de ceci' ou 'de cela'