# Comment utiliser « y » dans une phrase avec « il y a » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Dans une phrase comme « il y a des fleurs sur la table », si nous remplaçons « sur la table » par *y*, comment procédons-nous ?

Answer (score 3):

On ne peut pas mettre deux fois *y*, d'autant plus que celui qui est présent peut être considéré comme faisant déjà référence à *sur la table*.

> On voit des fleurs sur la table.
>
> On y voit des fleurs.

En conservant la locution *il y a*, on peut écrire :

> Il y a là des fleurs.

Voir aussi: [Que remplace le pronom « y » dans l'expression « il y a » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6664/que-remplace-le-pronom-y-dans-lexpression-il-y-a)

Answer (score 1):

Pour un remplacement dans la phrase même, il n'y a pas de possibilité d'utiliser « y »; il faut remplacer « il y a » par une tournure dans laquelle « y » devient un pronom avec un référent.

> Il aperçoit une grande table ; dessus, s'y trouvent des fleurs.

On peut cependant écrire ces phrases  plus simplement comme suit ;

> Il aperçoit une grande table ; dessus, se trouvent des fleurs.

Comment: « Y » n'est pas un pronom relatif.